# how to have multiple power line adapters on the same store

Tags: ethernet, home-networking, powerline-networking

I have a TP-Link ethernet-only power-line adapter that works like a charm. But my needs have changed and now I want to connect two more devices, one that will work as an access point in another room and one more for a smart tv's internet access.

My current setup is this:

One power-line adapter is connected to the modem/router and two more are connected to a laptop and the second router which will be used as an access point on separate fuses. I have already configured my second router to work as an access point and it works fine when it is the only power-line adapter I use in the house.

But when I use more than one power-line adapter, both lose internet access (while I do not get any error messages).

How can I set this up to work as I explained first?

One of my thoughts is to connect two get a network switch to get more ethernet plugs in my basic modem/router and connect all the power-line adapters as independent sets (so in the end I will use 3 sets) instead of one to three that I have now. I do not try it because I do not want to invest money on something that I am not sure that it will work.

Any ideas, even if not completely sure about them, are welcome.

Comment: Are all powerline adapters joined to the same network key? Are you sure you didn't end up having both routers act as DHCP servers?

Comment: What do you mean with "the same network key"? I am pretty sure I have disabled dhcp on the second router, but I will double check it.

Comment: Just like Wi-Fi devices support multiple networks on the same "air space" and join the chosen network by its name (ESSID), Homeplug powerline devices also support multiple networks on the same wiring and identify a network by its network key.  TP-Link has a Windows app for managing the devices. Are all of them listed when connected?

Comment: Second, have you looked at the computers' IP configuration? Compare both the 'working' state and the 'non-working' state. Does the computer have the same IP address on both occassions? Does it use the same gateway? Same DNS servers? Does `arp -a` show the same MAC address for the gateway?

Comment: When you get a solution, please post it, including diagnostic steps.    TPLink do have a support number https://www.tp-link.com/uk/about-us/contact/   And sometimes the company you get them from have good support too.

Comment: And it doesn't sound like much of an investment to get a network switch, they can be pretty cheap, (maybe $10?), that seems like a worthwhile experiment   You should get the network switch and cat5 cable 'cos what'd you do if things go down. It sounds like you are effectively the IT guy, besides running the store/home.

Comment: You write "the only power-line adapter I use in the house." You can't use one powerline adaptor otherwise it won't have another to connect to. So you mean one set. One pair. Also you can do all your experiments with 3. So one and a half sets, (excluding a cheap network switch you might want to experiment with, and some cat5 cable). You already have enough powerline adaptors (3 i.e. 1.5 pairs) to experiment with to see what works. If you have 3 working there's no reason why a fourth won't, unless you try plugging the fourth somewhere you hadn't tried plugging the other 3